# Proof of the limit of a function as X tends towards infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

How do I proceed with this proof where I'm trying to prove the limit of a function as X tends towards infinity.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfCDk.jpg)

Comment: The easiest would be to start by rewriting $\frac{2x-1}{x^3}$ to $\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}$ and showing that the two terms go to $0$ separately. Or perhaps just squeeze it, since $$0 < \frac{2x-1}{x^3}<\frac{2x}{x^3}=\frac2{x^2}$$ when $x$ is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x^3}$ and $\epsilon>0\;$ given.

we have

$$(\forall x>\color{red}{1})\;\;\; |f(x)|<\frac{2x}{x^3}=\frac{2}{x^2}<\frac{2}{x}$$

thus, if we have $ \frac{2}{x}<\epsilon$ then we will be sure that
$\;\;|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Put $A=\max(\frac{2}{\epsilon},\color{red}{1})$.

we can write

$(\forall x>A)\;\;\; |f(x)|<\frac{2}{x}<\epsilon$.

$$\implies \lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0.$$